# When I click in the TabBar item , The Entire TabBar disappears.... , Swift , Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5, xcode12

I don't know why this is happening , but if you do , PLEASE let me know .
When I click in the TabBar_ProfileButton , go to the Profilepage , then click again in the TabBarButton_ChatButton, and go to the ConversationView, the TabBar Disappears. I don't know why....
I tried to call the tabBat isHidden = false to not disappear, and because the first navigation Controller the TabBar is hidden because it doesn't have to appear in the welcomeView , loginView or registerView.

[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgA6H.jpg),[Storyboard - WelcomeVC - Descriptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktIsj.png),[Storyboard - ConversationVC - Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tETMD.png),[ConversationVC Swiftfile - Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBcJz.png),[First time ConversationVC Loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1f2pz.jpg),[First time ProfileVC Loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUjHF.png),[Second time ConversationVC Loads - TabBar Disappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9smq2.png),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set constraints for your tableView or change the contentInset of it. Otherwise your tableView appears on top of your TabBar that is why it disappears

try using this code:
`tableView.contentInset.bottom = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height ?? 0`

Please be sure to put your code next time and not just make screenShots because it is uncomfortable for others to read!

Comment: Thank you!  I'll make sure to put the code next time , sorry , it was my first post ;)